# How to use the Markdown class in Yii

Tags: php, markdown, yii

I see there is a Markdown class `CMarkdown`, but how do I use it?

There's no examples anywhere and the methods aren't self explanatory.

Do I use it statically like `CHtml`, or weird like a Widget?
Or do I have to `init` it somewhere like a Model?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [CMarkdown](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CMarkdown) as a widget in a view like this:

```
$this->beginWidget('CMarkdown', array('purifyOutput'=>true));
echo $content;
$this->endWidget();
```

When the $content contains Markdown syntax it will be processed by the widget. The array contains values for the public properties of CMarkdown. The properties are documented [in the class reference](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CMarkdown).

CMarkdown is used in the Yii blog example and you will find it in [this view file](http://code.google.com/p/yii/source/browse/tags/1.1.7/demos/blog/protected/views/post/_view.php).

Comment: Even more output buffering... That sucks. Thanks though! This is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 6):

This works and is imo the easiest:

```
static function markdown( $str ) {
    $md = new CMarkdown;
    return $md->transform($str);
}
```

A static function in the parent Controller. Probably not the Yii way, but it's simple:

```
<?=self::markdown($post->body)?>
```

Comment: You are correct, that would not be the Yii way. For your usage, it's best to instantiate CMarkdownParser, not CMarkdown, as the former is simply a wrapper to Markdown, and the latter is a Yii output parser, which uses CMarkdownParser. Your method, while it works, incurs more overhead. ||| EDIT: the only difference being, your method results in the markdown CSS being registered as well. Not sure if that's your desire.

Comment: Overhead schmoverhead. It's 26 times more readable and only half the letters. I've abandoned Yii a long time ago though. [Go ROW!](https://github.com/rudiedirkx/Rudie-on-wheels/blob/master/example_app/views/blog/index.php#L19)

Comment: Not saying a static helper function wouldn't be useful, just debating your usage of CMarkdown, since that is a gateway to CMarkdownParser (at least, in the way you're using it) whereas you can skip CMarkdown entirely and simply instantiate CMarkdownParser. Congrats on your own framework regardless.

Comment: I think I've read and understood this for the first time. Ofcourse CMarkdownParser would be more efficient. You were right and I was a douche =) You're a patient fella!